# Old movie somewhat related to "Creature from the Black Lagoon": scuba divers explore a submerged UFO

Tags: story-identification, movie, ufos

I am trying to remember a sci-fi horror picture that has a quasi (as I remember it) connection to "Creature from the black lagoon".

The major part that I remember is that scuba divers find a submerged UFO. While exploring it, they open a door to a room with some type of machine in it. After activating it, accidentally, the machine pushes out a cylinder the size of a large soup can encased in ice.

I believe that the scuba divers not wanting to do anything else, leave the room and swim back to their base. The block of ice melts and exposes the metal can inside. Somehow the metal can opens up and what comes out is a "creature from the black lagoon" type "gill-man".

Additional information is that it seems that the movie may be a quasi-precursor to "Creature from the Black Lagoon" because it points out things about the birth of the creature that is not in the movie but can be found on wiki.

Comment: Sounds like the wiki is referencing the novel "Time's Black Lagoon" - but I don't think there is a film version of that. Also - was the film in question from the 50's or later? B&W or color, etc....

Comment: I am pretty sure that its "Destination inner space" that lee-eckhardt posted. If you have read "Times Black Lagoon and you watch the film, you may be able to tell us if, as I suspect, its a movie that tells a bit of the "Black Lagoon story" that was'nt in the film. Especially where the creature came from, the fact that he was an extraterrestial. thx.

Comment: When I saw the question title, I was really hoping for a Humanoids From the Deep reference (the 1980 version).  :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am pretty sure this is *[Destination Inner Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Destination_Inner_Space)* from 1966, although it has been a good long time since I saw it.

[image: Movie Poster]

> The story centers on a group of researchers working in an underwater laboratory. After an encounter with an Unidentified Submerged Object (USO—an undersea flying saucer), the base is attacked by a monster that may be the vanguard for invading aliens. The researchers and the base's military staff must deal with the creature and destroy the USO.

It does exist in full on YouTube:

Comment: This has to be it! Thanks highly. I havent yet viewed it but your description fills in the parts of the movie that was'nt clear so well that I "now" know what the movie was about :) .  Gonna look at it soon. If by chance its not it, I will enjoy this one anyway. thx.

Comment: I had a chance to view it and {drumroll}....it "is" the movie. Its funny how the passage of years changes what someone "thought" they saw. I was sure that the frozen cylinders that were the creature(s) in some type of suspended animation egg pod, were cylindrical in shape. Turns out that they were distinctly triangular in shape. How could someone forget that! I also saw the ice cubes come out on a conveyor belt. Not. On the floor of the underwater ufo. It was so long ago, I believe that I saw it on a b&w tv set. Dont remember the makeup of the creature, pretty good though. thx again.